# "The comparative ... the comparative" using both adjective and adverb

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question about the sentence structure "the comparative adjective ... the comparative adjective" and "the comparative adverb ... the comparative adverb." (As in, "The more he practiced, the better he played.")

My question is, is it fine when one of the comparatives is an adjective, and the other is an adverb? When you are talking about people whose lives became busy, can you say this sentence?

> The busier their lives became, the less frequently they saw their
> friends.

I am not sure if this sentence is fine because "the busier" is an adjective, but "the less frequently" is an adverb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement in English grammar that a single sentence must contain only comparative adjectives or else only comparative adverbs. A sentence containing a comparative adjective may contain a comparative adverb.

Some purist might insist (but I would not) that it is poor style to have a comparative adjective in one parallel clause and a comparative adverb in a different parallel clause. Such a purist might write

> The more hectic their lives became, the less frequent were their visits with friends

Such a rewrite admittedly strengthens the parallelism. But parallelism is just one aspect of style, and a natural and relaxed syntax is a different aspect of style.

Your sentence is fine.

Comment: Why you have said: "the less frequent **were** their visits with friends"? Shouldn't it be "the less frequent their visits with friends **were**"?

Comment: Both are grammatical.

Comment: I they identical in terms of the meaning the convey? I think "the less frequent were their visits with friends" is the inverted form which indicates emphasis.

Comment: You may be right with respect to **spoken** English although emphasis there also depends on volume and pitch. In written English, other means would likely be required to give emphasis. “As the degree to which our lives become more busy, our degree of engagement with friends decreases much more.” The resources of written English are less numerous than those of spoken English, which is why many quite articulate speakers of English are not excellent writers of English.

Comment: Can we also invert the first part and say: "The more hectic **became** their lives, ..." without change in meaning?

Comment: Yes, but placement of the verb “be” is more flexible than is true for verbs generally.  Putting “became” before the subject is somewhat awkward.